# input with labels in content box remaining width

Tags: html, css, width

I'm having some troubles with my styling of my custom content box. The content box contains of a few `label` and `input` fields. The content box has a `width` of `500px.

Some of the `labels` are longer than others, however the input should always be as big as the windows (- a bit of white space).

This is the HTML I have right now:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <label for="test1">This is a test #1</label>
        <input type="text" name="test1">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="test2">This is a test #2</label>
        <input type="text" name="test2">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="test3">But this is a test with a much longer label</label>
        <input type="text" name="test3">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.content {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.row {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

input {
    width: 385px;
}
```

As seen in the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/4ga3533o/ you can see that the first 2 `'rows'` work correctly, however by the third one, the `input` is below the `label` because the width is longer than the content box, how can I get it to work so the labels can have different lengths but the width only takes up the remaining space of the width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: flex` would be the best solution for your issue. Try this code.

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="form-wrap">
    <label for="test1">This is a test #1</label>
    <input type="text" name="test1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-wrap">
    <label for="test2">This is a test #2</label>
    <input type="text" name="test2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-wrap">
    <label for="test3">But this is a test with a much longer label</label>
    <input type="text" name="test3">
  </div>
</div>

.content {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

input {
  width: 385px;
}

.form-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.form-wrap label {
  width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this worked, really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can **`flex`**

```css
.content {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
.row {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: flex;
}
input {
  flex: 1;
}
label {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="test1">This is a test #1</label>
    <input type="text" name="test1">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="test2">This is a test #2</label>
    <input type="text" name="test2">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="test3">But this is a test with a much longer label</label>
    <input type="text" name="test3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already changed my code to Aryan's answer so I accepted that answer, though I appreciate your answer as well :)